# How to correct the CSS?

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #new_dom {
    height:200px;
    width:600px;    
  }

  #new_dom span {
    width: 100px;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
</style>    


<div id="new_dom">

  <span>One one one one one one one one</span>
  <input type="text" name="one" value="" />
  <br />

  <span>two two two two two two two two two</span>
  <input type="text" name="two" value="" />
  <br />

  <span>three three three three three three</span>
  <input type="text" name="three" value="" />
  <br />

  <span>four four four four four four four</span>
  <input type="text" name="four" value="" />
  <br />

  <span>five five five five five five five</span>
  <input type="text" name="five" value="" />

</div>
```

Hello,
why the width of the span is not working?  It seems do not be set to 100px

Answer (score 5):

`Span` is an inline element.  It will not accept `width` without being made a `block` or `inline block` element.

To fix this you need to do something like

```
#new_dom span {
    width: 100px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: do i have to use a <div> instead of <span>?

Comment: No, you can use `span`.  Although, as @Lapple mentioned, you should probably use `label` for descriptions of `input` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` to your `span` declaration.

**Explanation:** span is an inline element, and therefore cannot have a fixed width, it will normally span to fit the inner text.

---

*Offtopic:* I might be wrong, but I feel that you'd better use `label` ([specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9)) tags instead of `span`.

Answer (score 2):

`span` tags are **inline** elements, so they do not obey widths or heights.

If you want to set the width of an inline element, you need to set `display: inline-block` (works for IE 7+), or `display: block`, or float the element.

Answer (score 0):

spans are inline elements that means that width cannot be set on them.  If you want to set the width do the following:

```
#new_dom_span { display: inline-block; }
```

However that has the potential to cause other issues if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 0):

Change the style:

```
#new_dom span {
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    font-weight:bold;
  }
```

It should for now.